# PHP input type file check if empty

Tags: php, file

So I have this form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="data" value="send">
</form>
```

And this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    if($file){
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'not ok';
    }
}
```

Why does it echo 'ok'? Shouldn't it echo 'not ok'? How would I get it to echo not ok?

Comment: Your question stands at winning the **"Unclear what you're asking"** award of the day.

Comment: It echo's OK because it's most likely a valid file. To get it to echo NOT OK, then use conditional statements based on the allowed file types and/or size allowed. Nobody bothers reading manuals anymore, yet alone Googling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function [`is_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php):

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
    echo 'ok';
else
    echo 'not ok';
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(isset($_POST['data'])){
>
> $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
>
> if($file != "" ){
>
> ```
>   echo 'ok';
> ```
>
> } else {
>
> ```
>    echo 'not ok';
> ```
>
> }
>
> }